# How to get x and y position of JPane in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, positioning, jpanel

I have a JEditorPane in a JPanel. I want to know how far from the left and the right the JEditorPane is from the edge of the JPanel (or the frame as they are the same).

Is there a way to do this?

The Reason Is: I want to put a gradient on the JEditorPane that aligns to the edge of the JPanel in stead of the JEditorPane. The reason I want to do this is because there is a gradient on the JPanel and I don't want the JEditorPane background to appear to cover up the gradient. I would set the background to transparent but I got screen paint issues that I was unable to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `getLocation` on your `JEditorPane`. The location of a `Component` is relative to its parent.

Comment: Well, ended up not needing to anyway. I finally fingered out how to make it transparent.